# Is there way to keep whole Hexadecimal Colors after cssutils's serializing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, web-scraping

**cssutils**'s serializer turns **Hexadecimal Colors** to **Shorthand Hexadecimal Colors** by default. Example:

```
>>> import cssutils
>>> hex_d = cssutils.parseStyle('color: #aaaaaa')
>>> hex_d.color
#aaa
```

As you can see **#aaaaaa** was turned to **#aaa**. Is there way to config cssutils's serializer somehow to keep **full** Hexadecimal Colors in output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
_short_color_codes = re.compile(r'^#([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])$', re.I)

def get_full_hex(shorthand_val):
    return _short_color_codes.sub(r'#\1\1\2\2\3\3', shorthand_val)

hex_d = cu.parseStyle('color: #aaaaaa')
get_full_hex(hex_d.color)
```

I found the snippet in the [premailer](https://github.com/peterbe/premailer/commit/e5f73b074a4efb7898204e2fb122b62542494a2e) repo.

**UPDATE:**

After browsing through [cssutils](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils/) repo I found that there is a [`Preferences`](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils/src/1b9008927350cf34fee1d05622b03e734bc4fcf5/src/cssutils/serialize.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#serialize.py-79) class that takes `minimizeColorHash` parameter (by default its set to `True`). Setting it to `False` should prevent the default behaviour of minimizing colorhash from full size to shorthand.

There is currently a bug that does not allow to use boolean `False` value for instantiation of `Preferences` class. I have submitted a [PR](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils/pull-requests/18/fixes-instantiation-of-preferences-class/diff) to fix this issue. If you don't want to wait, you can apply the code in above PR directly in your local `cssutils` module to make it work immediately.

Then you can simply do:

```
import cssutils as cu
prefs = cu.serialize.Preferences(minimizeColorHash=False)
ser = cu.serialize.CSSSerializer(prefs=prefs)
cu.setSerializer(ser)
hex_d = cu.parseStyle('color: #aaaaaa')
hex_d.color
# #aaaaaa
```

Comment: It working good! Thank you! Just need to do it like this `cssutils.ser.prefs.minimizeColorHash = False`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [blowdrycss](http://blowdrycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) module. It needs `cssutils` as a dependency.

```
from blowdrycss import colorparser
hex_d = colorparser.ColorParser('color', '#aaaaaa')
print(hex_d.value)
#Output: #aaaaaa
```

Comment: Thank, i had never even heard of blowdrycss module. But, you see, i really do need to use exactly cssutils:(

Comment: blowdrycss also uses cssutils under the covers. If you are restricted to install this module then a little more research is needed to configure settings in cssutils.